# XAMARIN Forms - why the same form looks different on iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have decided to try Xamarin Forms, because I thought that I can make one design for all platforms or at least Android and iOS. 
However a simple form like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:app91="clr-namespace:App9;assembly=MasterDetail.Android"
             x:Class="MasterDetail.CompetitorsListPage"
             >
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="{Binding CurrentEvent.Name}"></Label>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Text="By Place" Clicked="Button_OnClickedByPlace"></Button>
        <Button Text="By Number" Clicked="Button_OnClickedByNumber"></Button>
        <Button Text="By Rating" Clicked="Button_OnClickedByRating"></Button>
        <Button Text="Change Event" Clicked="Button_OnClickedChangeEvent"></Button>
      </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <ListView x:Name="couples" ItemSelected="Comps_OnItemSelected" ItemTapped="Couples_OnItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Round}"></Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Pos, StringFormat='({0}).'}"></Label>
                                  <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                                  <Label Text="{Binding StartingNumber}" ></Label>
                                  <Label Text="{Binding OldRating, StringFormat=' [{0}]'}"></Label>
                                  <!--<Label Text="{Binding NewRating, StringFormat=' {0} ]'}"></Label>-->
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Looks **completely** different on Android and iOS. I do not mind colours, but font size? I do not set font anywhere in the code or xaml. 
Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Here it is a picture showing both versions:
[image]

Comment: Looks like Xamarin did a good job of making both apps look native on their respective platforms.  They're not supposed to look identical.  It's probably using the default font size for each table row, and that's just different on Android and iOS.

Comment: I agree with Egg, you can provide your own values for all of these, but by default it looks like it should on each of the platforms. There is an OnPlatform flag you can use to provide different values for each platform, or you can provide the same values for all platforms and things will look a lot more like each other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design.  Forms is intended to provide a *native* experience on each platform by using their respective UI standards.  Android has a different default color scheme than iOS.  iOS default buttons look different than Android.

You can override the default fonts, sizes, colors, etc if you like in order to provide a more consistent UI.  Xamarin has also introduced [Themes](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/) for Forms which help you provide a consistent UI between platforms.

Comment: I understand that colors are different, also that there is a different look. I am concerned more about two facts:
1. Different font size - how can I modify the code to fit the same amount of information in one line?
2. Strange behaviour on iOS - as you can see those are labels in StackLayout, while in Android they behave OK, in iOS second and third label behave more lithe they were in some kind of grid rather than stack

Answer (score 1):

Because Android has variety of screen sizes and different screen DPI as compared to standard dpi and font sizes across iOS devices, it is not possible to create same look. But you can certainly change Theme in the `MainActivity` of your Droid project and increase font size as per your convenience. Beware that your theme's font size may be too big for small devices and too small for big devices. You can add scaling factor for font size in your theme, but I have not been very successful, instead, I tried to design a UI that will automatically fit for the best.

As per Xamarin Evolve 2016, some questions were raised regarding font sizes, they said it is difficult, but they are trying to make some unified font sizing.

Although Xamarin.Forms has everything in Xaml and C#, you still need to use iOS assets and Android resources to customize look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

For me, @Jason's answer and comments from @Egg and @Bill Reiss are spot-on.

Meanwhile, so often clients request "same font size" across platforms that something like this finds its way into base Styles or Theme to account for what seems to be "natively smaller" fonts on Android:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Font">
    <OnPlatform.iOS>Bold,Medium</OnPlatform.iOS>
    <OnPlatform.Android>Bold,Large</OnPlatform.Android>
    <OnPlatform.WinPhone>Bold,Medium</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
</OnPlatform>
```

Something similar can also be expressed in code at or near app startup, for example as a base Label font added to global Styles dictionary.

Just wanted to give a concrete example of what others above alluded to.

Answer (score 0):

2. Strange behavior on iOS - as you can see those are labels in StackLayout, while in Android they behave OK, in iOS second and third label behave more lithe they were in some kind of grid rather than stack –

You have put 5 labels in a horizontal stack, and haven't changed the layout options on any of them.  This will 'stack' all 5 labels next to each other, then size them based on the amount of text to be displayed. There is not enough horizontal space to accommodate all of the text, so the labels are wrapping vertically.  The longest labels show the most wrapping, but as they get longer other labels wrap as well, which is why the Pos and OldRating data raps in some labels.  When I'm working out layouts like this I often add different background colors to each control so I can see how they are laying out.

There are different ways to solve this depending on your desired result.  If you want the entire line of text to wrap you can concatenate the data behind the scenes and add it as one label.  If you want the name to wrap and the other data to display without wrapping you can set WidthRequests on the labels.